# Scratchness detection/scoring on plastic/metal surface

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning

Scratch on plastic surface may have huge/tiny impact on product given the size, color, depth,I call the impact of those factors:"Scratchness".

Lighter color or smaller size of scratch may have tiny impact, we can give it score 1 for scratchness:
Darker color and bigger size may have huge impact on the product, we can give it score 5 for scratchness.
I have some example img here with scratchness score:

I am working on a solution to find a image based solution to detect the impact of scratch with noisy background, I can imagines two different solutions:

1. mathematics based image processing algorithm based on contrast and other characteristic of these imgs
2. deep learning with proper labeling, either classification or detection/regression.
   Please shed some light, I can provide more data in case needed

[score 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB6RC.jpg)

[score 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dal4S.jpg)
[score 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDFUT.jpg)

Comment: "surface defect detection". go find some research on it. this is the entire business idea of many companies.

Comment: Your question isn't likely to get an answer here, SO is for coding specific questions. By that I mean if you have some code that you cant get to work then by all means ask here. Your question is not of that type. That said, if have enough images (1000's)  then traning a [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) is probably the best way. Have a look at [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/)

Comment: Chris and DrBwts, thanks for answering , yes, I have a CNN based detection working, the solution tell me exact location of scratch , but I can't get a scratchness score with factors mentioned above, I am looking for some idea on how to do a regressing for the score.

Comment: that's just another regression/classification problem.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/machine-learning-image-grading/10262

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to how well a mathematics based approach will work but I can say that deep learning works well for this.

I've seen high 97+% per-class accuracy on similarly formulated "how scratched" classification problems by fine-tuning a transformer such as [CLIP](https://openai.com/blog/clip/).

Disclaimer: I work for an ML-as-a-service company so I'm probably biased toward ML solutions.